# linear regression is part of PCA but also an extention to it...(Truth or Bluff)

Tags: regression, pca

The question I’d like to ask is what is the correlation of regression and PCA.

From my understanding the correlations of a factor and its constituent variables is a form of linear regression – multiplying the x-values with estimated coefficients* produces the factor’s values**

- are they called factor loadings?
- are they called factor scores

And ,

- my most important question is can you perform (not necessarily linear) regression by estimating coefficients for *the factors* that have their own now constant coefficients)

Answer (score 0):

seems I found my answer at:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f7d6/bdbd63f784ef9badb087e9235f62fb74a5e9.pdf

After having understood that factor scores are a sumproduct of factor loadings(coefficients) and observations all you need to know to use FA or PCA in combination with linear Regression is on that paper...

except, maybe, if non-linear regression on the factors is possible(meaningful)